# MySQL query to maintain sort-order in ascending order for self-referencing table

Tags: mysql, self-reference

I am using `MySQL 5.6.17`.

I have a `self-referencing` table let us say `TableA` with columns `id (int), title (varchar(100)), parent_id(int), sort_order (int)`.

The `parent_id` column is a `foreign key` that refers to the `id` of the same table. In this way I maintain the `N level` of hierarchy.

The table data is as below :

```
id    title         parent   sort_order 
1     Item 1        NULL     1
2     Item 1.1      1        1 
3     Item 1.2      1        4
4     Item 1.3      1        5
5     Item 2        NULL     3
6     Item 2.1      5        1 
7     Item 2.1.1    6        4
8     Item 2.1.2    6        5
9     Item 2.2      5        3
10    Item 2.1.3    6        3
```

Here, the hierarchy is well maintained but **NOT** the **sort-order**. I want to *re-order* the items under each parent item.

The resultant data should be like below :

```
id    title         parent   sort_order 
1     Item 1        NULL     1
2     Item 1.1      1        1 
3     Item 1.2      1        2
4     Item 1.3      1        3
5     Item 2        NULL     2
6     Item 2.1      5        1 
7     Item 2.1.1    6        1
8     Item 2.1.2    6        2
9     Item 2.2      5        2
10    Item 2.1.3    6        3
```

I have tried the query shown below to `re-order` the sort order of each item under parent :

```
UPDATE TableA 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownumber := 0) r
SET TableA.sort_order = (@rownumber := @rownumber + 1)
WHERE TableA.parent IN (SELECT t.id FROM TableA t);
```

But it returns error

```
Error Code: 1093
You can't specify target table 'TableA' for update in FROM clause
```

If I *remove* the `where` clause from the above query then it resets the sort order for each item in ascending order but **I want each item under parent starts with sort order 1**.

Any idea how to achieve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (`id` int, `title` varchar(10), `parent` varchar(4), `sort_order` int)
;

INSERT INTO t
    (`id`, `title`, `parent`, `sort_order`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Item 1', NULL, 1),
    (2, 'Item 1.1', '1', 1),
    (3, 'Item 1.2', '1', 4),
    (4, 'Item 1.3', '1', 5),
    (5, 'Item 2', NULL, 3),
    (6, 'Item 2.1', '5', 1),
    (7, 'Item 2.1.1', '6', 4),
    (8, 'Item 2.1.2', '6', 5),
    (9, 'Item 2.3', '5', 3),
    (10, 'Item 2.1.3', '6', 3)
;
```

Query:

```
update t
join (
  select 
  t.*,
  @so := if(coalesce(parent, '0') != @p, 1, @so + 1) as new_sort_order
  , @p := coalesce(parent, '0')
  from t,
  (select @so := 0, @p := null) var_init
  order by parent, id
  ) sq on t.id = sq.id
set t.sort_order = sq.new_sort_order;
```

Result:

```
select * from t;

| ID |      TITLE | PARENT | SORT_ORDER |
|----|------------|--------|------------|
|  1 |     Item 1 | (null) |          1 |
|  2 |   Item 1.1 |      1 |          1 |
|  3 |   Item 1.2 |      1 |          2 |
|  4 |   Item 1.3 |      1 |          3 |
|  5 |     Item 2 | (null) |          2 |
|  6 |   Item 2.1 |      5 |          1 |
|  7 | Item 2.1.1 |      6 |          1 |
|  8 | Item 2.1.2 |      6 |          2 |
|  9 |   Item 2.3 |      5 |          2 |
| 10 | Item 2.1.3 |      6 |          3 |
```

Keep in mind, that you have to specify a column in the order by that determines the sort_order. I was assuming it's `id` in this case.

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2d01d/1/0)